# Select specific rows to be appended into google sheets via array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically I have an array of information that I can currently append into google sheets, the thing is that a lot of the information is not necessary for my need so I wanted to find a way to just append the columns I need.

[image: all information appended to gsheets]

The picture above shows how everything looks,

basically the idea is to make it looks like in the following picture.
[image: How it should look like]

so basically I only need to append columns 4,5,7

currently why I do is this!

```
     if (tozip.getContentType() == "application/zip"){  //for ZIP files
    var unZip = Utilities.unzip(tozip); //assigns the unzipped file to a new variable


    var table = Utilities.parseCsv(unZip[0].getDataAsString());// assigns the data to variable



  for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {//loops trought the array an appends the data as it goes.

    sheet.appendRow(table[i]);   


    }
```

the data comes from a csv file and looks like this.

> [[isApplication, applicationDate, isQualified, Funded_Date, isFunded, requested_loan_amount, amountFunded], [1, 2020-02-03, 1, 2020-02-03, 1, , 1300.0000], [1, 2019-12-29, 1, 2019-12-30, 1, 3000.0000, 2000.0000], [1, 2020-01-27, 1, 2020-01-28, 1, , 800.0000], [1, 2020-01-08, 1, 2020-01-10, 1, 2500.0000, 2500.0000], [1, 2020-02-04, 1, 2020-02-10, 1, , 1400.0000], [1, 2020-01-21, 1, 2020-01-21, 1, 5000.0000, 2000.0000], [1, 2020-02-06, 1, 2020-02-06, 1, 1100.0000, 1400.0000], [1, 2020-02-01, 1, 2020-02-04, 1, 1500.0000, 601.0000], [1, 2020-02-11, 1, 2020-02-11, 1, 500.0000, 800.0000]]

so yeah a lot of messy csv data.
I tried adding this to the code and a few variations of it so It can select the inside data

```
 for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {//loops trought the array an appends the data as it goes.
var columns = [];  
    columns.push(3);
    columns.push(4);
    columns.push(6);   

 sheet.appendRow(table[i][columns]);   

    }
```

but it does not work I'm super new to this type of stuff, so I'm pretty sure that's not the correct way to try and select the information I want from the array.

let me know if I need to elaborate more on this, I'm not super good at explaining this stuff.
Thank you in advance for the answers I really appreciate the help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the columns "D", "E" and "G" from the data retrieved by parsing the CSV data.

  - In your script, `table` of `var table = Utilities.parseCsv(unZip[0].getDataAsString());` is the 2 dimensional data shown in your question.
- You want to put the retrieved values to the Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- `table` of `var table = Utilities.parseCsv(unZip[0].getDataAsString());` is 2 dimensional array.
- When `for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {}` is used, each row can be retrieved by `table[i]`. And the values from the columns "D", "E" and "G" can be retrieved by `table[i][3], table[i][4], table[i][6]`.

  - In this modification, `var values = []` is prepared, and each row is put with `values.push([table[i][3], table[i][4], table[i][6]])`.
- When the method of `appendRow()` is used in the for loop, the process cost becomes high. So in this case, an array is created in the for loop. And the array is put to the Spreadsheet using `setValues()`. By this, the cost can be reduced.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var table = Utilities.parseCsv(unZip[0].getDataAsString());

// I modified below script.
var values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
  values.push([table[i][3], table[i][4], table[i][6]]);
}
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

- Above script, the values are put to "Sheet1". If you want to change this, please modify `getSheetByName("Sheet1")`.
- In this case, `table` is `var table = Utilities.parseCsv(unZip[0].getDataAsString())`.

#### Note:

- When `var table = Utilities.parseCsv(unZip[0].getDataAsString())` doesn't return the array of CSV data, above modified script cannot be used. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [parseCsv(csv)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: This works wonders!! Thanks a lot for this I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @Mario Solorza Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.